# Can't install any package that includes tqdm

Tags: anaconda, conda

The last couple of hours I've been updating my python and anaconda packages, but I have hit a wall regarding this tqdm package. The first thing I tried was installing nbformat with: 
`conda install nb format`

and got back:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
conda-package-handling: 1.6.1-py36h62dcd97_0
tqdm:                   4.46.0-py_0
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:                  4.3.30-py36h7e176b0_0 --> 4.8.3-py36_0
conda-env:              2.6.0-h36134e3_1      --> 2.6.0-1
menuinst:               1.4.10-py36h42196fb_0 --> 1.4.16-py36he774522_0
nbformat:               4.4.0-py36h3a5bc1b_0  --> 5.0.6-py_0
pycosat:                0.6.2-py36hf17546d_1  --> 0.6.3-py36he774522_0
vc:                     14-h2379b0c_2         --> 14.1-h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime:         14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_2 --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_2
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

`ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.46.0-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\sergi\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running conda clean --packages may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.`

`CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\sergi\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running`conda clean --packages`may resolve your problem.`

I tried updating conda, but I get the same thing:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.46.0-py_0'.
```

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\sergi\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

Finally I tried installing this tqdm package with `conda install -c conda-forge tqdm`, got the same error again.

I have also tried with `conda config --add pinned_packages defaults::conda`, but nothing seems to work.

If anyone has any idea of what's going on I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? Did you try to run `conda clean` ?

Answer (score 1):

first step: `conda install tqdm -f`

second: `conda update conda`